# OpenGL ES 2.0 Drawing Quad Crashes

Tags: android, opengl-es, vbo

I am having trouble rendering a quad in Android with OpenGL ES 2.0 using VBOs.

For some reason when I run the program, it crashes the emulator.  I am using Andy for the emulator. I have tried using the default emulator that comes with android, and in this case the app simply won't run. I am using eclipse as my ide.

I have managed to narrow down the problem to the render method of the Quad class.

I guess I am wondering is there a problem with the way I am setting up the VBOs and rendering them?

Here is my code:

Quad render method:

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD)
public void render()
{
    mat.useMaterial();

    GLES20.glFrontFace(GLES20.GL_CW);

    //Generate VBO Buffer Handles and assign it to 'buffers'
    GLES20.glGenBuffers(4, buffers, 0);
    GLES20.glGenBuffers(1, ibo, 0);

    //Positions

    GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffers[0]);
    GLES20.glBufferData(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer.capacity() * 4, vertexBuffer, GLES20.GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, vertexBuffer);
    //GLES10.glVertexPointer(3, GLES10.GL_FLOAT, 0, vertexBuffer);

    //Normals

    GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffers[1]);
    GLES20.glBufferData(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, normalBuffer.capacity() * 4, normalBuffer, GLES20.GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, normalBuffer);
    //GLES10.glNormalPointer(GLES10.GL_FLOAT, 0, normalBuffer);

    //Texcoords

    GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffers[2]);
    GLES20.glBufferData(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, texcoordBuffer.capacity() * 4, texcoordBuffer, GLES20.GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(2, 2, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, texcoordBuffer);
    //GLES10.glTexCoordPointer(2, GLES10.GL_FLOAT, 0, texcoordBuffer);

    //Colors

    GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffers[3]);
    GLES20.glBufferData(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, colorBuffer.capacity() * 4, colorBuffer, GLES20.GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(3);
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(3, 4, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, colorBuffer);
    //GLES10.glColorPointer(4, GLES10.GL_FLOAT, 0, colorBuffer);

    //Indices

    GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ibo[0]);
    GLES20.glBufferData(GLES20.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexBuffer.capacity() * 4, indexBuffer, GLES20.GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    //Draw

    GLES20.glDrawElements(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, indexBuffer.capacity(), GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_INT, indexBuffer);
    //GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, vertices.length / 3);

    //Unbind buffers

    GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
}
```

Also here is the Material class:

```
package com.game.shading;

import android.opengl.GLES20;

public class Material 
{
private final String vertexShaderCode =
                "attribute vec3 vPosition;"                    +
                "attribute vec3 vNormal;"                      +
                "attribute vec2 vTexcoord"                     +
                ""                                             +
                "void main()"                                  + 
                "{"                                            +
                "    gl_Position = vec4(vPosition, 0);"        +
                "}";

private final String fragmentShaderCode =
                "precision mediump float;"                     +
                "uniform vec4 vColor;"                         +
                ""                                             +
                "void main()"                                  + 
                "{"                                            +
                "    gl_FragColor = vColor;"                   +
                "}";

private int vertShader;
private int fragShader;
private int shaderProgram;

public Material()
{
    vertShader = loadShader(GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER, vertexShaderCode);
    fragShader = loadShader(GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, fragmentShaderCode);

    shaderProgram = GLES20.glCreateProgram();
    GLES20.glAttachShader(shaderProgram, vertShader);
    GLES20.glAttachShader(shaderProgram, fragShader);
    GLES20.glLinkProgram(shaderProgram);
}

public void useMaterial()
{
    GLES20.glUseProgram(shaderProgram);
}

public void cleanupMaterial()
{
    GLES20.glDetachShader(shaderProgram, vertShader);
    GLES20.glDetachShader(shaderProgram, fragShader);
    GLES20.glDeleteShader(vertShader);
    GLES20.glDeleteShader(fragShader);
    GLES20.glDeleteProgram(shaderProgram);
}

private int loadShader(int type, String source)
{
    int shader = GLES20.glCreateShader(type);
    GLES20.glShaderSource(shader, source);
    GLES20.glCompileShader(shader);

    return shader;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a problem with the way you set up the attributes. Taking one of them as an example (the same thing applies to all of them, as well as the index buffer):

```
GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffers[0]);
GLES20.glBufferData(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer.capacity() * 4, vertexBuffer, GLES20.GL_STATIC_DRAW);
GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, vertexBuffer);
```

In ES 2.0, there are two variations of the `glVertexAttribPointer()` call. They have different signatures in the Java bindings:

- One of them takes a `Buffer` as the last argument. It is used to specify that the vertex data should be pulled directly from the memory of the buffer passed in. This is commonly called a "client side vertex array".
- The other one takes an `int` as the last argument. It is used for attribute values stored in a VBO. The argument is then an **offset** relative to the start of the VBO.

You're using the first version of the call, while you have in fact a VBO bound. In this case, you need to use the second version. Since your attribute data starts at the beginning of the VBO, the offset value is 0:

```
GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
```

Then correct the same problem for the other attributes and the indices.

I also don't see code that associates the vertex attribute locations with the attributes in the vertex shader. One option to add that is to use `glBindAttribLocation()` calls *before linking* the program.